# How to get shrink these Colored Balls over the Liquid?

Tags: modeling, mesh, fluid-simulation, mantaflow, viewlayers

I'm doing a fluid simulation right now, and for some reason these particle previews are blocking me from seeing the mesh; which is fine underneath. I was trying to make these spheres smaller, but I can't find out where to do that. I'm currently working in a .25m cube, so it's a bit smaller than usual. Does anyone know how to do this? [[image: View from Viewport]

Comment: pls show us your blend file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *Liquid Domain* object has a particle system. It creates those balls (halos) you see. On the *Particle Properties* tab you can set the size of the halos for the viewport. Just change the value for *Particle Properties > Viewport Display > Size* (`0.1 m`):

[image: particle settings of the liquid]